# Efficient algorithm to find neighbour geometries that are visible / can be reached with a straight line from the query geometry

Tags: python, shapely

I have a list of lines in shapely.
The lines do not intersect, but may have starting/ending points at the same coord.

What I want is a function which takes a geometry and the list of lines and tells me which subset of the lines can be reached from my given geometry with a straight line.
This straight line would start on any point on the geometry, go in any direction, end when it meets another geometry and would be infinite if it doesn't meet any other geometries.

[image: Desc]

**Image Description:** Blue & Black: the list of lines; Red: The query geometry; Blue: The result

I am not looking for the closest other geometries, but the ones "visible" to the query geometry.

Comment: are all lines forming polygons ? Then you could filter out the lines that are not part of the blue polygon (poly.contains(line) ) The boundaries of the polygon will be visible if the polygon is convex, otherwise you need to check the lines in the concave portions

Comment: @radouxju The lines form a connected graph with 1 component, but some line endings are loose (not met by other lines)

Answer (score 1):

Here a proposition of process :

We have as parameters :

- a line geometry to query (in red on your schema) : `query_line`
- a layer with a lot of lines (in black on your schema) : `lines_layer`

So :

- get the extent of `lines_layer`
- get the extent of `query_line`
- create a buffer on `query_line` that is more large than the extent of `lines_layer` (the extent of `query_line` will help to get the radius of the buffer)
- transform the buffer boundary into points at regular intervals
- transform the `query_line` into points at regular intervals
- create all the possible lines between `query_line` points and buffer boundary points
- select the `lines_layer` that intersects the `query_to_boundary` lines, they are solution (blue on your schema)
- select `query_to_boundary` lines that **not** intersects `lines_layer`, if there is a selection, so, they are infinite solutions.